# What was wrong in my question that it got downvoted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, specific-question

Why was my question downvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785072/how-to-run-a-script-whenever-there-is-net-activity

**Please briefly tell me what exactly went wrong**:

- Was it in the context
- or is the question unacceptable
- or is it totally irrelevant to the question but the way I asked it?

Comment: How about because you **want to spy on people**?!

Comment: Lol. . . well the idea was not mine but my friend's, my project idea was rejected by my mentor which was making an interactive tutorial of algorithms on android . . .so I was clubbed with him.

Comment: Okay, so you want to help your friend spy on people. Exactly **why** is this better? Why **shouldn't** your question be downvoted to oblivion?

Comment: I had to do a project what can **I** do ?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I might get that the downvotes are to suggest disapproval of the purpose of this question, but does that warrant closure as off-topic?

Comment: Ok I got my answer, it was the **context**.Thanx for the additional downvotes and in my **defence** it was **not my idea**.
Thanx Jack

Comment: Do you think that "it was not my idea" is actually a valid excuse?

Comment: No it is not coz I **supported** the idea, you are right but tell this thing to my mentor.

Comment: I don't really see how this question is off-topic.  Not constructive, perhaps.  Too localized, likely.  But not *off-topic*.

Comment: @JackManey I guess we all get the point now. Is there really a need to drag this out?

Comment: Indeed, closing as off-topic was not really appropriate. The question is related to programming and can be answered ("have your app poll the network interfaces", "write a device driver"). I can understand *why* we don't want to answer it, and we sure can refrain from doing that, but closing, especially as off-topic, goes a little too far.

Comment: This seems to be similar to [How to send 100,000 emails weekly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly), a question that was (rightfully) downvoted into oblivion but remains open.

Comment: Your question is unethical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that by now the reason for the downvotes will be crystal clear to you. As the comments have indicated, users don't seem to particularly appreciate you asking for help to spy on people. It's a bit more of a moral issue than I like to use my downvotes for (I would simply not answer) but each user is free to use their votes as they see fit.

As for the closure, that's another matter altogether. I don't think that this particular question deserves closure. And if it does, then certainly not as off-topic. Technically speaking it's a fair enough question not to be closed as off-topic. Any moral issues to me are no justification.