# Help with dubious-looking password checking scripts?

Tags: discussion, ethics, security

A user has asked for assistance on a web-based multiple password-checking script for [Tesco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203014/tesco-curl-script-need-help-on-input-method) and [Izotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282202/how-cabn-i-use-ajax-to-stop-php-timout-in-my-curl-script) websites. I can't think of any legitimate uses for this - even if the OP is intending to operate a "trusted third party" service, I should think users willingly divulging their credentials for these sites is a breach of standard T&Cs.

There's another [Tesco one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225836/curl-and-php-html-not-logging-in-correcty-i-know-curl-functions-work) from the same user, asking a related question. This one has attracted some answers, but no-one has asked what the OP is trying to do - or whether they should be doing it in the first place.

I appreciate that refusing to answer questions for ethical security reasons is not going to stop people trying. But users like this (who in this case, putting it politely, probably don't present much of a security risk) could be re-educated. And helpful helpers might also be encouraged to enquire about the end purpose. What does the community think?

Comment: Bah, I ask a question, and _then_ notice [this possible dup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices). Though, to be fair, that one's about mobile device jail-breaking, which has plenty of ethical uses.

Comment: [Closing questions with suspicious requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165445) is more general and closed as a dupe of the question you've found. Several of the answers there are also not specific to jailbreaking. I think that may be the canonical Meta post on this topic, but I'm going to poke around for another minute before voting.

Comment: reminds me of ismytwitterpasswordsecure.com

Comment: Thanks @Josh. I've asked the OP for a use-case on the two questions I've pointed to, for his/her potential edification `:)`.

Comment: Your own judgement is your best guide here, as it's a gray area like the other question you linked to, so it's tough to make a hardline decision about it.

Comment: The possible dup suggests we shouldn't help with "software cacking" - I certainly don't like the sound of that, whatever it is!

Comment: It's possible that he may be developing it to grab his own account details etc, but it does look a bit _iffy_. Probably breaks Tesco T&Cs too.

Comment: @nickhar The Izotope one is more blatant: `when checking more then 20+ email:pass`.